# Performance between declare 3 int vs. new int[3]

Tags: java, performance

I have 3 code snippet to measure the cost, the last snippet shows that maybe the main entry adding some cost, the main point still lied in first two snippet
First case: declare 3 int comes first

```
int size = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
long ms = System.currentTimeMillis();

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    int a = 10;
    int b = 20;
    int c = 30;
}
System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis() - ms));

ms = System.currentTimeMillis();

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    int[] arr = new int[3];
    arr[0] = 10;
    arr[1] = 20;
    arr[2] = 30;
}
System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis() - ms));
```

Output:

```
9
2
```

Second case: new int[3] comes first

```
int size = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
long ms = System.currentTimeMillis();

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    int[] arr = new int[3];
    arr[0] = 10;
    arr[1] = 20;
    arr[2] = 30;
}
System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis() - ms));

ms = System.currentTimeMillis();

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    int a = 10;
    int b = 20;
    int c = 30;
}
System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis() - ms));
```

Output:

```
8
1
```

Third case: I doubt that the main entry is somehow affect the cost so

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
int size = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
long ms = System.currentTimeMillis();

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    int a = 10;
    int b = 20;
    int c = 30;
}
System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis() - ms));

ms = System.currentTimeMillis();

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    int[] arr = new int[3];
    arr[0] = 10;
    arr[1] = 20;
    arr[2] = 30;
}
System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis() - ms));
```

Output:

```
1
2
```

So what is the reason of the first execution always slower than the second? I thought of memory allocation, and new int[3] is slower by logic, but how can the execution order changed that?

Comment: Your entire benchmark is flawed because it does not take into account the warmup effects of the JVM. You can't draw any conclusions from bad data. Use JMH, explained in the linked question

Comment: "but how can the execution order changed that" JVM/JIT warmup

Comment: You’re only measuring how long it takes until the JVM recognizes that the code does nothing useful and can be eliminated.